# Is Lua programing offer me flexibility for developing mobile (Iphone /Android Tabs)Business applications of enterprise level?

Tags: android, iphone

I am a beginner in Mobile apps development..I want to develop application for business purpose..but all I found is Lua is basically used for gaming...and it can be used for both I phone and android using CORONA SDK and im also need same but i m in dilema whether it could be used for making business app ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *could* but I wouldn't really advise it unless you have some very specific need in mind. Corona is very much targeted towards gaming. Perhaps you should explain why you think you want Lua and what kinds of features you think it will help you with in an enterprise application.

Comment: Hey thanx kabuko, I want to develop application for enterprise level,for instance,a software for hotel in which a customer will navigated through tab(application software) for accessing the facilities available which i'm developing with the help of android which i find flexible for development but this same scenario i want to repeat for iphone i find corona SDK for cross platform development which uses Lua Scripting but its syntax is basically for game(as i saw)and i thing it will lead me to complexity in future while development so which one will be suitable language (which i can use)?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for just something to help w/cross-platform. You can look at [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/), or one of the many other HTML5-based cross-platform tools.